# What is meant by determine $(G\times G)/D$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $D:=\{(g,g) \in G \times G: g \in G\}$

Determine: $(G \times G)/D$

I do not even know what is being asked for here. Any ideas?

Must I determine a particular map with the homomorphism theorem?

Comment: You mean of course $(G \times G)/D$, and since if $G$ is non-commutative $D$ is not a normal subgroup of $G \times G$, it is probably intended for you to find representatives of the cosets of $D$ in $G \times G$.

Comment: I agree that it is very unclear what is being asked for here.

Comment: Or to find an isomorphism of the $(G\times G)$-set of cosets of $D$ with a more familiar $(G\times G)$-set.